# JavaScript - check string for substring and capitalize substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How would I test a string to see if it contains a specific substring and then capitalize that substring?

```
var string = " A Fine and Rare George Iii Neoclassical Ormolu Urn Clock"
```

And find and capitalize the Roman numeral to III.

Another example:

```
var string2 = "Platinum Pf00673"
```

Find and capitalize letters in strings that contain numbers, so the above becomes `PF00673`

Comment: I'm guessing that the downvote is due to the fact that you have asked two questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the callback to `String#replace`.

```js
var string2 = "Platinum Pf00673";
var result = string2.replace(/\w*[0-9]\w*/g, match=>match.toUpperCase());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match and replace.

```
var string2 = "Platinum Pf00673"

var reg = new RegExp("[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z0-9]+", "gi");

var matches = string2.matchAll(reg);

for(var match of matches)
{
  var parts = string2.split("");
  
  parts.splice(match.index, match[0].length, ...match[0].toUpperCase().split(""));
  
  string2 = parts.join("");
}

console.log(string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to create a helper function like so

```
const capitlizeSubStr = (string, substring) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(substring, 'gi')
  const newString = string.replace(regex, substring.toUpperCase())
  return newString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering for the Roman Numeral question.

```
var string1 = "A Fine and Rare George Iii Neoclassical Ormolu Urn Clock";
var result = string1.replace(/M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})/ig, match=>match.toUpperCase());
console.log(result);
```

It's an extension of hev1's answer.

Answer (score 0):

capitalize romans:

```
'world war Iii'.replace(/\w+/g, word => word.match(/^[MCDXVI]+$/i) ? word.toUpperCase() : word)
// "world war III"
```

capitalize words with digits

```
'Platinum Pf00673'.replace(/\w+/g, word => word.match(/\d/) ? word.toUpperCase() : word)
// "Platinum PF00673"
```